# Subview of custom UIButton class doesn't trigger click

Tags: ios, uibutton, subview, user-interaction

I'm writing a custom UIButton subclass, to create my own fully customized button
to have total controll. Still, I'm having problems when I try to add a subview
to that UIButton's view. The subview blocks the "touch" events so it won't bubble to 
the UIButton itself..

This is a demonstration: 
I first create my CustomNavigationButton, with a frame.. It's magenta.
I can see the magenta on the screen so it's there. Secondly, I add a subview
to that CustomNavigationButton (which is green), I can see the green so it's
there, but if I click the green rectangle (subview), the "UIControlEventTouchUpInside"
doesn't get called on my CustomNavigationButton..

In my AppDelete:

```
CustomNavigationButton* mapBtn = [[CustomNavigationButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25)];
mapBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
[mapBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goMapHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:mapBtn];
```

And here's my CustomNavigationButton class (which is a subclass of UIButton)

```
@implementation CustomNavigationButton
@synthesize bg;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // STORE INITIAL FRAME
        self.initialFrame = frame;

        bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 40, 40)];
        bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [bg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self addSubview:bg];       

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to do it! 
If "bg" is the subview I'm adding to the UIButton, then you should do:

```
bg.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
bg.exclusiveTouch = NO;
```

But keep in mind that, if your subview extends the frame of the UIButton,
a touch will not occur! You can check if your subview exceeds the UIButton
by giving the UIButton a background-color.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy!